# getBody always returns null in Apps Script even though that's how I think it should be written

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

My code is intended to make editing easier in Google Docs, but doesn't quite work and returns getBody null. I've already tested setting "body" as a variable, but that doesn't quite work. Due to how inexperienced I am with Javascript, it's hard to wrap my head around why *exactly* getBody returns null. So, it'd help me for the future if you knew where I'm going wrong with this.

```
function myFunction() {

var searchResult

searchResult = 
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText("very",searchResult)
Logger.log(searchResult)

while (searchResult !== null)searchResult.getElement().asText().setAttributes(searchResult.getStartOffset(),searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),"#FF000")

  searchResult = 
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText("very",searchResult)

}



function highlightProblem() {

var words = ["very","so","totally","really"] 

words.forEach(findText)

}


function onOpen(){
DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('everythingisnotfine.avi').addItem('Higlight Words That Make You Sound Like a Dandy', 'higlightProblem').addToUi()
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and put the code from the comment inside.

Comment: oh sorry kinda new here

Comment: This is better but you should put your question text first and then your code. That's because people who are monitoring the tags (i.e. questions they might wanna answer) are seeing the first sentence or so on the main page. So, ideally, your first 1-2 sentences tell what the problem is (or at least give a hint at the problem at hand) so that more competent people can jump in to answer.

Comment: You can see what your question looks like on those pages by checking one of the tag pages like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script?sort=newest&pageSize=50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body is not null. Your first problem is in this line

```
searchResult = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText("very", searchResult)
```

you have `findText("very", searchResult)` while you do not have the variable `searchResult`. As per documentation this requires a `range` class (read [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findText(String,RangeElement)))

Next up is the whole mess here

```
while (searchResult !== null)
  searchResult.getElement().asText()
    .setAttributes(searchResult.getStartOffset(),
                   searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),
                   "#FF000"
                  )
```

I did some formatting to better see the whole `while` loop. First of all, this is an endless loop, because it will keep repeating as `searchResult` is never changed inside of the loop so this step is either skipped or will continue endlessly. Next up is this particular method:

```
.setAttributes(searchResult.getStartOffset(),
               searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),
               "#FF000"
              )
```

Please read up on the method [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setattributesstartoffset-endoffsetinclusive-attributes) as you are using it incorrectly. You are providing a `string` to the method, where it expects an `object`. In the same documentation page scroll down to the next method, without the offsets, it shows an example of how `attributes` should be formatted.

Next we move outside of the loops. This seems to be pointless

```
searchResult = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText("very",searchResult);
```

perhaps you meant it to be done inside the `while` loop? Because essentialy what you are currently doing is

1. Set `searchResult` from document.
2. Log `searchResult` object
3. Set `searchResult` attributes (since that looks like hex color code, I assume you wish to color the code). Do this while `searchResult` is not `null`.
4. Set `searchResult` from document
5. End

If this was meant to be inside the while loop then you need to add `{` after `while` and `}` after the last action you wish to happen in 1 iteration of the `while` loop.